# Create and push Branch from production to origin

Tags: git

To keep things short, I discovered our team had code in production branch  which may be out of sync with origin/master.  This has gone on for quite some time now. I'm assigning myself the task to correct this mistake. My plan is to get to production, create a branch, push the new branch to origin, then compare and merge to master (in github) so all is well (production branch will be in synched with master).

- Is this the right solution?
- Could I run into isssues on production while switching branches (from current to new and back to current)?
- Any pitfalls I should watch for in this process?

Thanks

Comment: Have you new commits on server or changes are still in workspace ?

Comment: As per your description branch production should have commits that are not there in master. Are there any commits in mater that are not there in branch production?

Comment: @Supun Wijerathne On production, there are uncommitted files. On origin master, I'm not sure if commits exist there that are. It in production.

Comment: @user3389171 you can check that with  "git log not" command. If you know that before hand .. your process would be pretty easy. :))

Comment: $git branch: 
* (no branch)
  master

$ git log not:
fatal: ambiguous argument 'not': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Comment: I believe I misunderstood your git log not comment...I'll have to reference the manual to get what I need exactly.